# How to test whether an element on the page or not under Selenium Webdriver, C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I searched on uncountable webpages, and did not get a good answer to my question.  I'm on Selenium 2.30 using C#.

I tried

```
if (browser.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath")).Displayed)
```

I tried

```
if (browser.FindElements(By.XPath("xpath")).Count !=0)
```

And also

```
IWebElement element = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath"));
if (element.Displayed == true)
```

They only work when the element exist, but if not, it will pull out the exception. But that's not necessary an exception, I have something in else{} statement to handle it, I don't want the webdriver just stop me at the first point.

What I'm doing right now is

```
IWebElement element = null;
try
{
   element = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath"));
}
catch
{

}
if (element != null)
```

This way works so far, but I don't think this is the best solution.  I appreciate if someone can show me a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it is acceptable, but at times you will be trying to run this after performing a prior action (eg. navigating to a page) and it is usually best to give a timeout value and utilise the following WebDriverWait method:

```
WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout));
element = _wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath(searchAttribute.attributeValue)));
```

This allows you to wait until the element exists on the page up to the timeout value (I use 5 seconds on the application I test). However, simple you can just use your code of `if(element == null)` then it is was not found. If you use the WebDriverWait, you will have to catch the exception if you do not want it to throw after the timeout.

Comment: Also have a look at the list of pre-canned expected conditions available to you if using an explicit wait:  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver.Support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs

Comment: Thanks Nashibukasan. Maybe here is a stupid question, but what are the differences between WebDriverWait and ImplicitlyWait?

Comment: Another question is, why I can't use if (browser.FindElements(By.XPath("xpath")).Count !=0)

Comment: `ImplicitlyWait` is a timeout set to be used for all following `WebElement` searches. `WebDriverWait` can be passed varying timeout values and can be used for different `ExpectedConditions`. I believe you could use your `Count != 0` code, however you would still benefit from using one of the Waits otherwise you will find it returning a Count of 0 very quickly if the element has not yet loaded.

Comment: I got an exception something like "An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occured in WebDriver.dll".  Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL 'http://localhost:7055/someurl' timed out after 60 seconds when using .Count != 0

Comment: Maybe post a new question involving the full details of your exception. However, unfortunately, it sounds a lot like [this issue](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/net-bindings-whaddaymean-no-response.html).